# Where can I get best resources to learn sql?

Tags: learning

I am very new to the databases just have basic knowledge about it.

> I want to learn sql language and dont know where to start. Please help me to start with it.
> And what is the difference between sql and PostgreSQL? What are the different languages to maintain databases.
>
> > Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a declarative data query language. PostgreSQL is a database which supports SQL (as do all RDBMS's). Oracle supports SQL, so does MySQL &c. There are differences - PostgreSQL is very ANSI compliant, whereas Oracle and MySQL not so much.

If you want to learn, Google SQL tutorials and maybe use [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/) (more servers) or [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) (a bit easier) to test - or just download PostgreSQL/MySQL/Firebird. The three of these are Open Source and free to use for any purpose, bar MySQL: you can't distribute a closed-source application using MySQL without paying a licence fee to Oracle because of the dual GPL/commercial licencing.

From here:

> - MySQL Commercial License for OEMs, ISVs and VARs Oracle provides its MySQL database server and MySQL Client Libraries under a dual
>     license model designed to meet the development and distribution needs
>     of both commercial distributors (such as OEMs, ISVs and VARs) and open
>     source projects.

What this means is that basically, if you want to distribute MySQL based apps without paying a fee, your app must be under the [GPL version 2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html).

You can also download Oracle XE for free (latest version as of 05/2018) is [still 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) - limitations from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html):

> - Oracle Database XE can be installed on any size host machine with any
>     number of CPUs (one database per machine), but XE will store up to
>     11GB of user data, use up to 1GB of memory, and use one CPU on the
>     host machine.

There's also:

[Microsoft SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) with limitations 1GB RAM and 10GB data - from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express).

Your question is very general (too broad) for this forum - you need to read a couple of books/tutorials and come back with specific questions (with what you've tried - use one of the fiddles above for your DDL for your sample data (`CREATE TABLE...`), DML (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...);`) in your questions.

Comment: There is also SQL-Server Express.

Comment: "*free to use for any purpose*" is not true for MySQL because of it's GPL license: you are not free to distribute it with your non-GPL application and it's not free if you create a derivative work based on it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! FInally got round to updating the post - I'm doing a bit of spring-cleaning of my old (newbie) posts <cringe...(sometimes!)>